# JavaScript pushing an object in an array is what - by reference or value?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

When I create an object and push it to an array, is it stored by reference or value?

I see the following happening:

```
var abc = { a: 10, b: 20};
var def = [];
def.push(abc);

abc.a = 100;

def[0].a; // outputs 100!

// if I do this
abc = { a: 10000, b: 20000 };

def[0].a; // still 100, no change this time
```

Image from console:

[image: Image from console]

If I use the `=` sign to assign an object to `abc`, the reference pointed by `abc` in the array `def` should also change, isn't it?. What do we call above, by value or by reference?

I have understood it like `abc` is a reference pointing to a value. As long as we don't use `=` sign, it will keep pointing to that. Please guide.

Comment: Change a property of one object and you'll see. If the other object changes as well, they both referred to the same object. Otherwise they were copies.

Answer (score 9):

Let's have a look at what is happening:

```
var abc = { a: 10, b: 20};
```

A new object is created in memory and assigned to the variable `abc`.

```
var def = [];
```

A new array is created in memory and assigned to the variable `def`.

```
def.push(abc);
```

Inside the array there is now a pointer to the formerly created object.

```
 abc.a = 100;

 def[0].a; // outputs 100!
```

Obviously right. We are modifying the object, which is also referenced by the array.

```
 abc = { a: 10000, b: 20000 };
```

Again a new object is created and a reference to it is stored in `abc`. Now we have two objects (and an array) in memory.

```
 def[0].a; // still 100, no change this time
```

Of course, this is still `100`. The array pointer still references the first created object and not the second one.

Comment: Great detailed break-up of what's going on!

Comment: 1. From the 1st answer, it seems that inside the array, **there is value** and not a pointer - and that value being pointed externally by `abc`. 2. the object is not referenced by the array, but by literal `abc`. So if `abc` looses its pointing, we can't externally modify the object inside the array

Comment: btw, I did not downvote. I m still confused for pass by reference and value. Any good resources?

Comment: @OmShankar pass by value means that you just create new copy of data, and pass by reference means that you copy only pointer (memory address) of data that reference same object on heap

Comment: @OmShankar Like mentioned in the first answer, objects are just referenced. So, if you assign a new value to `abc` the old reference will be overwritten, but not the actual object. If there are any other references to that object, they will remain. If there are no reference to the old object, it will be taken care of by the garbage collection.

Comment: cool, but remember that the passed object still refer to the same value. 

try replace this action:
 `abc = { a: 10000, b: 20000 };`
with:
`abc.a = 9999`

, then accessing def[0].a will gives you 9999

Answer (score 7):

Objects are ALWAYS passed by reference.

When you write `abc = { a: 10000, b: 20000 }`, what you are overwriting is the *variable* `abc`, which was pointing to the old object, but is now pointing to the new one.

Comment: Of course that assignment assigns a new object to abc, but that doesn't say anything about passing objects by reference.

Comment: So what happens to the `abc` inside `def`. It seems `def` just had the **value** which was pointed by `abc`. So can we call this pass by value?

Answer (score 0):

as you said `create an object` so then you are dealing with references.

in your second statement `abc = { a: 10000, b: 20000 };` what you actually did is just make variable `abc` pints into new object make it reference to something else than the old `abc`

Answer (score -3):

The reason of the problem is when you push the object to array, it clones it self. I mean in the array there is a clone of the object. Therefore if you change the properties of the object, there is nothing will change. Because you have had 2 object already. If you want to overwrite it you have use def[0] = abc after definition of abc with new values. Except for the fact that you can not change the values without asigning it

Comment: You obviously do not understand the difference between value and reference type...

Comment: Why you think so ? I meaned that there is no pointer to point object in the array. There is new object in the array. Maybe it's wrong of course

Comment: Array just hold pointer to the same object reference on the heap, by pushing **abc** object into **def** array you just create new copy of pointer that refer same object

Comment: I try to explain same thing. I also thing like you